I need to point different domains from one server and different cpanel account into 1 folder ( Cpanel, WP Multisite )
I have a WP Multisite with multiple domains
"domains are placehodlers here"
repair.com - primary domain
dallas-repair.com - secondary
sanantonio-repair.com - secondary
Those 3 are in the one CPANEL accountI need to remember the following information:
I have a WordPress Multisite with multiple domains:
- repair.com - primary domain
- dallas-repair.com - secondary
- sanantonio-repair.com - secondary
All three domains are in one cPanel account. However, I have another account with the domain allacrepairhouston-repair.com, which should also be added as a secondary domain into the Multisite network.
The server is the same with the same Shared IP address (54.39.20.111). Both domains have A records and CNAME records pointed to this IP (54.39.20.11). However, the domain allacrepairhouston-repair.com, which is on another cPanel, still can't be added to the Multisite network. It is fetching local files instead of files from the primary domain (repair.com). I have added A records and CNAME records for the secondary domain, but it is still fetching local files instead of files from the primary domain.
but I have another account with
allacrepairhouston-repair.com - which also should be added as secondary domain into multisite network
The server is the same with same Shared IP address (54.39.20.111 - also a placeholder)
Both domains have
A records and CNAME records pointed to this IP (54.39.20.11)
but "allacrepairhouston-repair.com" that is on another CPANEL still can't be added to Multisite Network, it just fetch local files instead of files from primary domain (repair.com)
I have added A record and CNAME record for secondary domain
allacrepairhouston-repair.com. 14400  A 54.39.20.11

allacrepairhouston-repair.com.  14400  repair.com

But it is still fetching local files instead of files from primary domain
